# Getting a console reading while a loop is running

Tags: java

I want to create a program that has a user playing darts. You have two random number generators both going from 0 to 10 that repeat constantly. If you hit enter the code stops and if it lands on 6 that your Y coordinate. Than another generator starts from 0-10 and you hit enter and it stops on a 2 your Y coordinate is 2. My issue is that if the Console is waiting for an input the code won't run. I need to find a way for the code to run and still accept an input which than stops the loop.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Code excerpts and error traces?

Comment: This site is primarily a debugging site, with some exceptions such as help with IDEs. For us to help you, you need to write your own code, and present it here if you can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by the input that stops the loop? If you have two random generators what do you want to input? only Enter key?

Comment: Since you are a new user. Welcome to Stackoverflow . Please add code to your question. Tell us what have you tried?. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing  service. You should learn How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an infinite while loop where inside the loop you are doing the random number generator and checking if anything is read in from the keyboard. If there is something read from the keyboard you save the current generated number and `break;`. You then would do something similar for the other coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Multithread might helps. You can create one thread for looping and another thread for input console. Create a static variable as a flag to stop the loop in the loop thread once the input thread notices the user hit enter.